How do i specifically save the data without it showing in the jTable?
I want the program to be precise on putting the data in the Jtable, without messing up my sql database.
The Jtable structure only has, NAME, USERNAME, EMAIL, PASS, GENDER, and STATUS.
my sql database table structure is lastName, firstName, middleName, username, password, email, gender, birthday, address, status. The data thats being recorded in the table are not in order, and also the way it adds onto the jtable are not in order.
Also ive combined that when my data shows up in the jtable, the lastname and firstname are combined. (spacing problems).
sql data
[heres whats happening)
(https://i.sstatic.net/VC4FAU7t.png))
code:
  DefaultTableModel tabolmodel =
    (DefaultTableModel) jTable4.getModel(); // add string array basta yon
if (tabolmodel.getRowCount() == 0) {
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Table is Empty.");
} else {
  try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
    java.sql.Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
        "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/shsgrading?useSSL=false", "root", "");

    for (int i = 0; i < tabolmodel.getRowCount(); i++) {
      String NAME = (String) tabolmodel.getValueAt(i, 0);
      String USERNAME = (String) tabolmodel.getValueAt(i, 1);
      String EMAIL = (String) tabolmodel.getValueAt(i, 2);
      String PASS = (String) tabolmodel.getValueAt(i, 3);
      String GENDER = (String) tabolmodel.getValueAt(i, 4);
      String STATUS = (String) tabolmodel.getValueAt(i, 5);

      String lastName = txtLname.getText();
      String firstName = txtFname.getText();

      if (NAME.contains(", ")) {
        String[] names = NAME.split(", ", 2);
        lastName = names[0].trim();
        firstName = names[1].trim();
      } else {
        firstName = NAME;
      }

      String middleName = txtMname.getText();
      String address = txt_address.getText();
      java.sql.Date sqlStartDate = null;
      java.util.Date utilStartDate = date_birthday.getDate();

      String status = "Inactive";

      int statusMaxSize = 30;
      if (status.length() > statusMaxSize) {
        status = status.substring(0, statusMaxSize);
      }

      String query =
          "INSERT INTO instructor(lastName, firstName, middleName, username, password, email, gender, birthday, address, status) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

      PreparedStatement prepstmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
      prepstmt.setString(1, lastName);
      prepstmt.setString(2, firstName);
      prepstmt.setString(3, middleName);
      prepstmt.setString(4, USERNAME);
      prepstmt.setString(5, PASS);
      prepstmt.setString(6, EMAIL);
      prepstmt.setString(7, GENDER);
      if (sqlStartDate != null) {
        prepstmt.setDate(8, sqlStartDate);
      } else {
        prepstmt.setDate(8, new java.sql.Date(new java.util.Date().getTime()));
      }
      prepstmt.setString(9, address);

      if (STATUS != null && !STATUS.isEmpty()) {
        prepstmt.setString(10, STATUS);
      } else {
        prepstmt.setString(10, status);
      }

      prepstmt.executeUpdate();
      prepstmt.close();
    }

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Data inserted successfully.");
    tabolmodel.setRowCount(0);
    con.close();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "An error occurred: " + e.getMessage());
  }
}




I don't see how that code is relevant really. It only reads from your JTable so if that's as shown in the (bad link-text) linked image, then whatever wrote that table model is the wrong code, and that's not shown

if (sqlStartDate != null) will always be false, since you set it to null

“The data thats being recorded in the table are not in order” —SQL database records don’t have a defined order.  It is never correct to assume that the order in which you inserted records is the order they’ll be returned in a subsequent query.  If you want them in a specific order, add an ORDER BY clause to your SQL query.

A JTable delegates to a few models. The most important is the TableModel. This contains the data, and should contain all columns.
A second model is the TableColumnModel. This determines which columns are actually shown in the UI. It has methods to add, move and remove columns. You can use this to remove the column that you don't want to show.
There's a third model, the ListSelectionModel. This determines which rows or separate cells are selected.
With functionality like moving columns in the UI, and row sorting, JTable has some methods to map between the UI and the TableModel. For instance,  convertColumnIndexToModel converts from a UI column index to the matchign model index, and  convertColumnIndexToView converts the other way around.
